# Orthonormal polynomials and recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonality, orthonormal

I read a book where there is this example:

> The recurrence relation holds for polynomials $\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots$ with $\deg(\pi_n)=n$

$$x\pi_n(x)=a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)+b_n\pi_n(x)+a_{n-1}\pi_{n-1}(x)$$

> then these are orthonormal polynomials
> with $a_n=\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}$ where $\pi_n(x)=\gamma_nx^n+\dots$.

I have especially troubles to understand why $a_n=\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}$ and there is no derivation.

Edit: I remove my solution since it is an exercise. I keep the final result though.

I can show the recursion for monic polynomials $p_n(x)$.

$$xp_n(x)=a_np_{n+1}(x)+b_np_n(x)+c_{n}p_{n-1}(x)$$

But here I am lost.

Comment: This relation definitely does not hold for ALL orthogonal polynomials and ALL inner products... Look again at the book and check which inner product they are using and what other properties $\pi_n$ have

Comment: @N.S. I accidently wrote it wrong. It says: the polynomials for which this recurrence relation is true. The inner product should be with respect to the Lebesgue measure. I actually do not have a good proof of it.

Comment: Does the problem also tells you that $\deg(\pi_n)=n$?  If not the claim is clearly wrong, since you can shift the index of $\pi_n$.

Comment: @N.S. Yes it does.

Comment: @Somos I have seen this one too. But also the other one, I am not really sure what exactly the difference is but I believe the other one is only for orthonormal polynoms.

Comment: From the equation $\,x\pi_n(x)=a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)+b_n\pi_n(x)+a_{n-1}\pi_{n-1}(x)\,$ and defining $\, a_n := \frac {\gamma_n} {\gamma_ {n + 1}},\;\; p_n (x) := \frac {\pi_n(x)} {\gamma_n}\, $ you immediately get $\,xp_n(x) = p_{n+1}(x) +b_np_n(x)+a_{n-1}^2p_{n-1}(x).$

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Favard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem) is very relevant regarding orthogonal polynomial solutions of three term difference equations such as for $\,\pi_n(x).$

Comment: @Somos Thank you, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$
x\pi_n(x)=a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)+b_n\pi_n(x)+a_{n-1}\pi_{n-1}(x)
$$
What is the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ on the LHS? What about on the RHS?

Make them equal and then you are done.

Comment: I don't get it. I end up with $\gamma_n=a_n\gamma_n$. We have to use $\gamma_{n}$ for the LHS on the $ x^{n+1}$ term. And the RHS is $a_n\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}\gamma_{n+1}=a_n\gamma_n$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Matriz On the RHS, $x^{n+1}$ only appears in $a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)$. Note that the other two terms have degree at most $n$. The coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)$ is $a_n\gamma_{n+1}$. How did you get $a_n\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}\gamma_{n+1}$ on the RHS??

Comment: But I have shown the recursion only for $p_n$ and not for $\pi_n$. So if I replace on the RHS $p_{n+1}$ with $\frac{\pi_{n+1}}{\gamma_{n+1}}$ I get $a_n\frac{\pi_{n+1}}{\gamma_{n+1}}$. And the $\gamma_n$ on top is from the LHS. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Matriz Your post is very confusing... The way you state the problem, I understand that the relation $$x\pi_n(x)=a_n\pi_{n+1}(x)+b_n\pi_n(x)+a_{n-1}\pi_{n-1}(x)$$ is given you you. If you know this relation, then the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ on the LHS is $\gamma_{n+1}$ and on the RHS is $a_n \gamma_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Matriz On another hand, if from the relation which is given to you, you can deduce that $$xp_n(x)=d_np_{n+1}(x)+e_np_n(x)+f_{n}p_{n-1}(x)$$ for some $d_n,e_n,f_n$, then your mistake was denoting two DIFFERENT things by the same thing: $a_n$: the ratio of $\gamma_n/\gamma_{n+1}$ AND the coefficient in the relation you get among $p_n$'s.

Comment: @Matriz Now, if you know that $$xp_n(x)=d_np_{n+1}(x)+e_np_n(x)+f_{n}p_{n-1}(x)$$ then, the fact that $p_{n+1}$ and $p_n$ are monic tells you that $d_n=1$. Therefore $$x\pi_n(x)=\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}\pi_{n+1}(x)+e_n\pi_{n}(x)+f_{n-1}\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n-1}}\pi_{n-1}(x)$$ which is exactly what you need....All your confusion is coming from the fact that you denoted by $a_n$ both $\frac{\gamma_n}{\gamma_{n+1}}$ and the number $1$.

Comment: @Matriz Also, next time please make it clear: what you know and what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Now it is clear. Yes I will.